# How to color and alignment spinner item on android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm try to change text color and align item in spinner to center of it how can I do this

here is my code

```
    String[] li={"1","2","3"};
final Spinner combo = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.widget30);
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, li);
combo.setAdapter(a);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a custom view for that, and specify by calling:

```
a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Note that you have to use your own view here: R.id.my_simple_spinner_dropdown_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Comment: Very nice... worked for me.  Seems odd to be styling a Spinner with a TextView, but it certainly works.  Do Spinners somehow inherit text colors without styling them this way?  On emulator, I had different behavior than on phone.  Phone gave me white text on white background... obviously a problem.  This technique allows me to force visibility.

Comment: There is a big downside to this solution. In order to set items RTL you need to give it a width of fill_parent or match_parent. How align items RTL when using wrap_content for TextView? since we usually want the width of our spinner be equal to the largest item width.