# Align spinner values to right instead of left

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, alignment, spinner

In spinner xml, I'm using:

```
 android:entries="@array/cars"
```

where cars is list of numeric items.

The spinner automatically align values to left, and I can't find in xml/code how to change it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use a custom view here to give alignment to the Spinner values. Create a CustomView like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491980/how-to-color-and-alignment-spinner-item-on-android) answer has created and add `android:gravity` to the TextView as `right`.

**UPDATE:**

Set the CustomView to your adapter using

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.your_custom_created_view);
```

Comment: 10x. but now how I can load to this spinner/textView the array of values?

Comment: 10x again. I can add adapter to my code, but I can't set my custom view to this adapter because it's now "TextView" and not a Spinner.

Comment: [Here is how you should go to make it custom spinner item](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/924-tutorial-custom-spinner-with-icon)

Comment: As of now, alignment of the selected item of a spinner can be changed by `android:gravity="right"` directly. I'm not sure when they changed this ...

Answer (score 15):

You can use `TextAlignment` on properties and select `TextEnd`,
or `android:textAlignment="textEnd"` on XML simple

Comment: You must *also* specify `gravity` or `layout_gravity="end"`

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with spinner item text alignment right end :**

```
view.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END
```