# Android Spinner Gravity Not working

Tags: android, alignment, spinner, gravity

I'm trying for days to align the text in a spinner to right, but every time I fail to do it,
I tried to set Gravity to right, or ellipsize to end but nothing works and all I have is this :

[image]

can you please help with this issue ?

Thanks a lot.

Here's the XML :

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnCities"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:entries="@array/array_cities"
    android:gravity="right"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCities"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/city"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: Could you post your xml?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491980/how-to-color-and-alignment-spinner-item-on-android

Comment: thx Silverstorm, tried this, but this acts on the dropdown items, all I want is that view (see pic) becomes wrapped (in fact wrap_content too is not working)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to use a custom view to enable this to work.  Use google its your best friend...this will probably help:

[Align spinner values to right instead of left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629768/align-spinner-values-to-right-instead-of-left)

Comment: This is right solution, although it looks like while using Spinner width wrap_content it does not work. It does work only with weight, dp length or match_parent,

Answer (score 0):

android:textDirection="rtl"

Comment: Maybe you want to expand on your thought?

Comment: I meant that you may want to explain that so that the Original Poster (OP) can understand what it is, how to use it, and how it will be helpful.