# Changing the color of the spinner

Tags: android, spinner

[image: Spinner Color]

In this picture you can see (barely lol) that the spinner icons that rest on the bottom and bottom right are very hard to see due to the black background that I am using.  What would I need to do to make that greyish looking color to white or any color for that matter?

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491980/how-to-color-and-alignment-spinner-item-on-android?rq=1

Comment: @romedius Nope.  I don't see anything on there about changing the gray color.

Comment: looks like, you got Holo light on a black background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this tutorial:
[Android Custom Spinners](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57)

A similar process is used for working with custom buttons and other elements.

Updated as the link is broken. Try this stackoverflow answer
[Spinner Background Design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550512/1759409)

Comment: Dont use links, this may be dead at longer time. Above is already dead link, Better give solution over here.

Comment: How about suggesting a link or posting a collection of information here rather than downvoting and posting a comment about it. This post is over 3 years old and would benefit from a refresh rather than a verbal spanking. Answers here should be brief and efficient. The OP is quite vague but may benefit from checking this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13550512/1759409