# Right Alignment for Spinner via Java (Not via XML)

Tags: java, android

**Spinners need to be Right aligned on the Screen**

I tried to use everything like setGravity and other, Nothing worked.

I tried to search also a lot for this Right alignment, everywhere solution is available in **XML** format but **NOT** in Java format.
Can someone Please help :)

[image: Spinner needs to be Right side of the screen]

Code

```
        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setEnabled(false);
        ll.addView(spinner);
        lm.addView(ll);
```

Abir : Now its showing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you. It's a bit complex, cause it has multiple nested views. But this will solve the issue and i think you will get the view you want.

```
    final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setWeightSum(1);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    final CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
    box.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .1f));

    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .3f));
    tv.setText("STD_MOBILE");

    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .6f));
    l2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setEnabled(false);


    l2.addView(spinner);

    ll.addView(box);
    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(l2);
    lm.addView(ll);
```

I have used weight to specify the exact space for your childViews. Then made the Spinner's parent layout's gravity to right.

Comment: its working Abir. Thanks for all the effort you have put in. :)

Comment: i'm glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem:

```
    final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setEnabled(false);
    ll.addView(spinner);
    lm.addView(ll);
```

You should set your dynamic linearLayout's width and height. and then set its gravity to RIGHT. Then your spinner will be aligned on the right side of the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) But now everything is going to Right. I think because we setGravity for Linearlayout, It has shiifted everthing.

Comment: Please find the new image @top. I need only Spinner to Right most side.

Comment: I thought you only had one child as Spinner.

Comment: I have 3 ...1CheckBox, 1TextView & 1 Spinner. I want only Spinner Right Aligned. Can you please help? :)

Comment: So you want a CheckBox, then a TextView after that a Spinner. Now my question is, Do you want the spinner right after the TextView or aligned at the end of the view?

Comment: Spinner is already after TextView. I want only Spinner aligned at the end of the view. i.e. After textView, there will be some space and then Spinner will Right Aligned.

Comment: i have provided another answer. check it out, i hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom view here to give alignment to the Spinner values. Create a CustomView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491980/how-to-color-and-alignment-spinner-item-on-android) answer has created and add android:gravity to the TextView as right.

Set the CustomView to your adapter using

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.your_custom_created_view);
```